# Jquery mobile: link back to index.php doesn't fire pageshow again

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, event-handling, jquery

I've got a simple website using jQuery mobile. It's composed of 2 pages, `index.php` and `pageB.php`. In `pageB.php` is the jqm pages' header. I put a link back to `index.php`:

```
<a href="index.php">Retour</a>
```

In `index.php`, the page id is `welcome`

My problem is that if I

1. Enter the site from domain.com/
2. Click on a link to `pageB.php` (ajax-loaded)
3. Click on the link back to `index.php`

The event `pageshow` is **not fired again** and the content, which I loaded dynamically before, is not present. (Seems to be a new page of type #welcome)

But if I replace the link in `pageB.php` with a link to `index.php#welcome`, `welcome` being the id of the page in `index.php`, then if I enter the site from `pageB.php`, the **link is inactive**.

Update:
Here is simplified code to reproduce the problem:

`index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Explicit charset definition -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 "/>
    <!-- useful for mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Includes javascript & css files required for jquery mobile -->
    <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role=page id=welcome>
        <div data-role=header>
        <h1>Index</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role=content>
        <a href="pageB.php">link to pageB</link>
        <script>
            $('#welcome').bind('pageshow', function(){
                alert('pageshow triggered');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `pageB.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Explicit charset definition -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 "/>
    <!-- useful for mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Includes javascript & css files required for jquery mobile -->
    <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role=page id=pageB>
        <div data-role=header>
        <!--<a href="./index.php#welcome" data-icon="arrow-l">Retour</a>-->
        <a href="./index.php" data-icon="arrow-l">Retour</a>
        <h1>PageB</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role=content>
            nothing
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code.  We can't debug without it.

Comment: i added a sample code, i'm affraid nothing really particular could cause this issue to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following solution:

First, create a javascript file and call it `test.js` for example. In this file, include the following code:

```
function myfunc(){
    alert('pageshow triggered');
}

$(document).delegate('#welcome', 'pageshow', myfunc);
```

Then, include the following code for both your files `index.php` and `pageB.php`:

-`index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Explicit charset definition -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 "/>

        <!-- useful for mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Includes javascript & css files required for jquery mobile -->
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />

        <!-- INCLUDE YOUR FILE 'test.js' -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="welcome">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Index</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="pageB.php">link to pageB</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

-`pageB.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Explicit charset definition -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 "/>

        <!-- useful for mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Includes javascript & css files required for jquery mobile -->
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />

        <!-- INCLUDE YOUR FILE 'test.js' -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="pageB">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="./index.php" data-icon="arrow-l">Retour</a>
                <h1>PageB</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">nothing</div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Another solution would be to group every jQuery Mobile pages in one HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Explicit charset definition -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 "/>

        <!-- useful for mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Includes javascript & css files required for jquery mobile -->
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />

        <!-- INCLUDE YOUR FILE 'test.js' -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- PAGE ONE -->
        <div data-role="page" id="welcome">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Index</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#pageB">link to pageB</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- PAGE TWO -->
        <div data-role="page" id="pageB">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="#welcome" data-icon="arrow-l">Retour</a>
                <h1>PageB</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">nothing</div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PS:** You may change the path / source of the file 'test.js' according to your convenience.

Comment: Hey mate, sorry I made some mistakes... Please try the code again (I changed my previous post). Normally it should work. Let me know about your results mate.

Comment: O__o... which solution did you use? the first one or the second one? The first one should be working, I'll test the second one in my environment.

Comment: I tested the second solution too and it works, what's not working? Do you see any alert message with "pageshow triggered"?

Comment: 1st solution works but the event is triggered twice
but with multipage template IE doesn't seem to fire the event pageshow on pageB.

the 2nd one does nothing

Comment: oh... you're using IE? huum... that may be the reason why I get another result :S (I'm using Firefox :) ). Wait mate, I'll change my post.

Comment: I modified the 1st solution, could you have a try and let me know?

Comment: i have to ensure the website is compatible with IE8+, bt am testing it with opera and chrome as well ;) 
pageshow is now triggered once when going from #pageB to #welcome but not on the firt #welcome load (so not when you load the webpage)

Comment: Ok. I've seen the same issue you were talking about (alert howing twice), with Opera :S... This is really a problem... I'm also trying to fix this in my side.

Comment: ok, i made some tests and updated jquery mobile 1.2 rc1 and the multipage templates seems to work as expected (which is strange...)

but with links between differents files it doesn't solve the issue: if i enter the website from domain.com/ the link on pageB.php to index.php works and pageshow isn't triggered again, but if i enter the website from domaine.com/index.php, pageshow is triggered when going back to index.php

Comment: argh!!! Ok mate, I changed my previous edit again... lol :). Try it and let me know if this works (it worked on Opera at last XD... I'll be dying soon lol)

Comment: i does neither work in opera nor in IE when i access the website from "/", but works when i access it from /index.php. The problem is that visitors won't change the url themselves.
I'm considering using a multipage template as you suggested earlier since it seems to be the only simple way to do this.

Comment: i'm definitely settling on this. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Your welcome! De rien! ^^ (I saw some French words in your code, I'm not sure whether you're French or not :) ). This was my first trickiest problem on SO :S. Quite interesting problem, especially when it comes with defining the `pageinit`event correctly, without calling it twice! :P